# Change bullet color (amCharts)

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Trying to change the bullet colour in my chart, but can't figure out how. The docs say the colour should inherit, but it's not doing so?

**Demo**:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
    "xValue": "Q1",
    "yValue": 3
}, {
    "xValue": "Q2",
    "yValue": 4
}, {
    "xValue": "Q3",
    "yValue": 7
}, {
    "xValue": "Q4",
    "yValue": 2
}, {
    "xValue": "Q5",
    "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";
theXAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
theXAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
theYAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
series1.fill = "#2c3e96";

series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.stroke = "#ffbb00";
series1.bullets.stroke = am4core.color("#ffbb00");
series1.bullets.fill = am4core.color("#ffbb00");
```

```css
body{
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```

I just want the blue bullets to become yellow, like the stroke.

Comment: ```series1.fill = "#ffbb00";``` ==> This makes the bullets get filled with the same color as the graph line

Answer (score 0):

`series.bullets` is a list, you can't set visual properties directly on it. You need the bullet object that you create from `new am4charts.CircleBullet()`; the demos on the AmCharts website use the return value of `push` and go from there:

```
var bullet = series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.stroke = "#ffbb00";
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#ffbb00");
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#ffbb00");
```

```js
var chart = am4core.create("dataChart", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
    "xValue": "Q1",
    "yValue": 3
}, {
    "xValue": "Q2",
    "yValue": 4
}, {
    "xValue": "Q3",
    "yValue": 7
}, {
    "xValue": "Q4",
    "yValue": 2
}, {
    "xValue": "Q5",
    "yValue": 9
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";
theXAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
theXAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
theYAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
theYAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = "#ff0000";

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY} / 10";
series1.fill = "#2c3e96";

var bullet = series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.stroke = "#ffbb00";
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#ffbb00");
bullet.fill = am4core.color("#ffbb00");
```

```css
body{
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="dataChart"></div>
```